# Getting user location in Android seems impossible

Tags: android, gps, location

I'm tryin for a couple of days to retrieve user's location but no succes.
The textview is not updating.
I've tried debugging but the location isn't received.

Here is my code:

**MainActivity**

```js
package com.pislaru.andro;

import android.location.Location;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationProvider.LocationCallback {

    public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private LocationProvider mLocationProvider;

    TextView t;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView t;
        t = new TextView( this );
        t = ( TextView )findViewById( R.id.text );
        t.setText( "Hello !" );

        mLocationProvider = new LocationProvider(this, this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mLocationProvider.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mLocationProvider.disconnect();
    }

    public void handleNewLocation(Location location) {
        t.setText( location.toString());
        Log.i( TAG, location.toString());

        double currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
        double currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();
    }

}
```

**LocationProvider**

```js
package com.pislaru.andro;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;

public class LocationProvider implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener {

    public abstract interface LocationCallback {
        public void handleNewLocation(Location location);
    }

    public static final String TAG = LocationProvider.class.getSimpleName();

    /*
     * Define a request code to send to Google Play services
     * This code is returned in Activity.onActivityResult
     */
    private final static int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;

    private LocationCallback mLocationCallback;
    private Context mContext;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

    public LocationProvider(Context context, LocationCallback callback) {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

        mLocationCallback = callback;

        // Create the LocationRequest object
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setInterval(10 * 1000)        // 10 seconds, in milliseconds
                .setFastestInterval(1 * 1000); // 1 second, in milliseconds

        mContext = context;
    }

    public void connect() {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    public void disconnect() {
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Location services connected.");

        try
        {
            Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
            if (location == null) {
                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
            }
            else {
                mLocationCallback.handleNewLocation(location);
            }
        } catch( SecurityException e ) { Log.i(TAG, e.toString()); }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        /*
         * Google Play services can resolve some errors it detects.
         * If the error has a resolution, try sending an Intent to
         * start a Google Play services activity that can resolve
         * error.
         */
        if (connectionResult.hasResolution() && mContext instanceof Activity) {
            try {
                Activity activity = (Activity)mContext;
                // Start an Activity that tries to resolve the error
                connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(activity, CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
            /*
             * Thrown if Google Play services canceled the original
             * PendingIntent
             */
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                // Log the error
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            /*
             * If no resolution is available, display a dialog to the
             * user with the error.
             */
            Log.i(TAG, "Location services connection failed with code " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mLocationCallback.handleNewLocation(location);
    }
}
```

**Manifest**

```html
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

What to do ? 
Mention that GPS is enabled on device and also from settings.
The device is connected to wi-fi.
Google Play Services are enabled.
I don't realise why this does not work.
I heard that is a package named smart-location. Is better that my code ?

Comment: you want to getting current location ??

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: What exactly does not work?

Comment: Why do you use Google Services if you want just to receive the user's location?

Comment: @TodorKostov then what to use ? My code does not have errors. Simply the textview does not update. The log function does not raise. Yes, i want the current location. And the posibility to update it with a button.

Comment: Check the first comment below the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145089/what-is-the-simplest-and-most-robust-way-to-get-the-users-current-location-on-a#comment23213772_3145089

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just delete this two lines of code in onCreate():

```
TextView t;
t = new TextView( this );
```

Comment: fkin hell, i can t believe this was the solution ! million thanks ! is my code ruining the battery?